# Cannot return null for non nullable field GraphQL - express, graphql app

Tags: angular, express, graphql, apollo-client

I have been tinkering with GraphQL recently and I am struggling to get my head around mutations and resolvers. I have been trying to create a function on a booking application where a booking is deleted by ID. A booking looks like this

```
type Booking {
        listing_id: String! 
        booking_id:String!
        booking_date:String!
        booking_start:String!
        booking_end:String! 
        username:String!
    }
```

So on click on the button on my app, this booking_id is taken in and deletes the said ID.

```
updateBooking(
            listing_id:String!
            booking_id:String!
            booking_date:String!
            booking_start:String!
            booking_end:String!
            username:String!
        ):Booking 

        deleteBooking(
            id: ID!
        ): Booking
```

This is my deleting booking mutation, from my research this seems to be correct. However I am running this with an express app and have been making use of playground to test my mutations. Below is my test mutation. I have stored the ID as a variable. It is throwing errors like `"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Booking.booking_id.",`

```
mutation delete($id: String){
  deleteBooking(id: $id){
    booking_id
  }
}
```

In my express app I am calling like below.

```
deleteBooking: async (parent, args) => {
            console.log(args)
            if (!args.id) {
                return JSON.stringify({ status: false, "message": "No ID found" });
            }
            return await Booking.findByIdAndDelete(args.id)
        },
```

I've been playing around with this test project for a few days and I am just at a loss with this as my add booking is adding without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following solution? In your mutation type file:

```
deleteBooking(id: ID!): String!
```

In your resolver:

```
deleteBooking: async (_, { id }) => {

        try{
            const booking = await Booking.findById(id);
            await booking.delete();
            return 'Booking deleted successfully';
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(err);
        }
    }
```

Hope it will work.